# How to apply attribute using Jquery "appendTo "

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing a code that reads in a JSON data and then create a table using appendTo. I am trying to apply an attribute  "href" to a `<td>` table field.  I have tried multiple ways, but I am unable to see the href inside the generated html code.

I am trying to have something like this in the generated code:

```
  <td><a href="#"> key1</a></td
```

What would be the best way to generate this kind of code?

http://jsfiddle.net/charles30hk/b3cqtnur/

```
var data = {"key1":{"key11":"value11",
                    "key12":"value12"},
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3":"value3",
            "key4":"value3",
            "key5":{"key51":"value11",
                    "key52":"value12",
                    "key53":{"key531":"value","key52":"value12"},
                    },
            };
function loop(obj, ul,nested=0) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if($.isPlainObject(val)) {
            //$("<tr>").appendTo(ul)
            for (i=0;i<nested;i++) {
              $("<td>").append().appendTo(ul)
            }
            $("<td class=link>").text(key).appendTo(ul)
            //$("td").last().attr("href","#")

            /*var ul2 = $("<td>").text("hello").appendTo(
                $("<tr>").appendTo(ul)
            ); */
            //var u12 = $("<tr>").appendTo(ul)
            if (i==0){
              $("<tr class=parent>").appendTo(ul)
            } else{
            $("<tr>").appendTo(ul)
            }

            //$("<td>").appendTo(ul)
            loop(val, ul,nested+1);
        } else {
            //$("<tr>").appendTo(ul)
             for (i=0;i<nested;i++) {
                $("<td>").appendTo(ul)
            }
             $("<td>").text(key).appendTo(ul)
            //ul+="<td>"+key+"</td>"
            $("<td>", {
                id: key
            }).text(val).appendTo(ul);
             if (i==0){
              $("<tr class=parent>").appendTo(ul)
            } else{
            $("<tr>").appendTo(ul)
            }
        }
    });
}


$(function(){
$("#products").on("click","a",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".parent").toggleClass("open");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the link inside the table cells where appropriate, by altering only this line

```
$("<td class=link>").text(key).appendTo(ul);
```

with this

```
$("<td class=link>").html("<a href=\"#\">"+key+"</a>").appendTo(ul);
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3cqtnur/3/)